# Sequence hava a segment in oracle? And a procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about Oracle Database.
Have a sequence a segment in Oracle? And a procedure have a segment too?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequences and procedures don't own segments in Oracle database. Oracle database stores metadata related to them in catalog structure.

You can check USER_\ALL_\DBA_SEGMENT views and you will not spot segment type SEQUENCE or PROCEDURE in column SEGMENT_TYPE ([Documnetation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/DBA_SEGMENTS.html#GUID-7BF4F8C7-1917-4532-B048-C044E17A1754)).

Comment: The catalog itself would be in the SYSTEM tablespace and have segments, so indirectly they would be on one.

Comment: So...have a segment or not?

Comment: Indirectly they will have one - by the fact that even the internal catalog's are still being stored in tablespaces which obey the same, page, extent, segment rules. Jacek is correct to state they do not own segments (directly)